# What is the difference between Authorize Action filter and Authorization filter?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, filter

As per the [ASP.NET website](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/understanding-action-filters-cs)

The ASP.NET MVC framework includes several action filters:

1. OutputCache – This action filter caches the output of a controller action for a specified amount of time.
2. HandleError – This action filter handles errors raised when a controller action executes.
3. Authorize – This action filter enables you to restrict access to a particular user or role.

Also,  there is a type of filter in MVC called "Authorization filter".

I am confused whether [Authorize] attribute is an Action filter or Authorization filter? And when will it be executed ?

Answer (score 6):

> What is the difference between Authorize Action filter and Authorization filter?

None.

That documentation is apparently incorrect (and if you note in the table of contents, it is for version 1 and 2 of MVC, so it is also out of date).

`AuthorizeAttribute` inherits `IAuthorizationFilter`, so it is in fact an authorization filter, not an action filter. **There is no Authorization action filter in MVC.**

Note that for MVC 3 to MVC 5 you should refer to the up-to-date [Filtering in ASP.NET MVC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg416513(VS.98).aspx) documentation in the future.

> And when will it be executed ?

As per [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg416513(VS.98).aspx):

> Filters run in the following order:
>
> 1. Authorization filters
> 2. Action filters
> 3. Response filters
> 4. Exception filters

Answer (score 2):

> I am confused whether [Authorize] attribute is an Action filter or
>   Authorization filter?

The `[Authorize]` attribute is an Authorization filter, as can be seen by looking at it's source code.  If you look closely, it implements the `IAuthorizationFilter` interface and according to the documentation, that classifies it as an Authorization filter.

```
namespace System.Web.Mvc
{
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Specifies that access to a controller or action method is restricted to users
    //     who meet the authorization requirement.
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, Inherited = true, AllowMultiple = true)]
    public class AuthorizeAttribute : FilterAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter
.........
```

> When is it executed?

As per the documentation:

> Filters are executed in the order listed above. For example,
>   **authorization filters are always executed before action filters** and
>   exception filters are always executed after every other type of
>   filter.

Have a look at the current documentation for filtering in MVC: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg416513(VS.98).aspx

It clearly states that the [Authorize] attribute is an Authorization filter:

> The AuthorizeAttribute class and the RequireHttpsAttribute class are
>   examples of an authorization filter. Authorization filters run before
>   any other filter.

Comment: I have seen the source code and that's when I got confused. Because as per  the ASP.NET website http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/understanding-action-filters-cs  , The ASP.NET MVC framework includes several action filters: -
Authorize – This action filter enables you to restrict access to a particular user or role.

Comment: This documentation is outdated I believe.  Have a look here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg416513(VS.98).aspx - it clearly states that the Authorize attribute is an Authorization filter.